# What is the meaning of "Paul’s in his late forties"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In this link [longman dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/late) it has written "Paul’s in his late forties". Which is the meaning?

1. the old of Paul is near to 50.
2. the old of Paul is near to 40.

I think number one is true. But I doubt about it.

Comment: Please we say **age**, not **the old**. Please look up how to refer to people's ages in English. Paul's age is x. But the word age is often left out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paul is aged 47, 48 or 49.

Talking about ages, 'the/someone's forties' are the years from 40 to 49. 'Early forties' are probably 40-43, 'mid/middle-forties' are probably 44-46 and 'late forties' or probably 47-49.

We can write 'forties' or '40s'.

('The forties' can also be the years 1940 to 1949 (or possibly any other century).)

(And we say 'Paul's age is' or 'Paul is' rather than 'the old of Paul'.)